# IQueryable<T> does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use Include extension on IQueryable set, but I have the following issue:

> Error 1   'System.Linq.IQueryable<.Model.InsuranceCaseType>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method
>   'Include' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable<.Model.InsuranceCaseType>' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

My code:

```
var allCaseTypes = Uow.InsuranceCaseType.GetAll().Include(a=>a.Geos);
```

Method `GetAll()` returns - `IQueryable<.Model.InsuranceCaseType>`

I have in scope the following namespaces:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Comment: The error message is telling you what is wrong. You are missing a using directive or an assembly reference.  **What namespace and assembly is the method in?**

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`Include` is not an extension method on `Queryable`, so it doesn't come together with all the usual LINQ methods. If you are using Entity Framework, you need to import the corresponding namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: This information is no longer accurate. The `Include` extension method is now located within `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure` which is within the `EntityFramework.dll` assembly. Reference that assembly to use that method.

Comment: Depends which EntityFramework I guess. I am using EF 5.0 and using System.Data.Entity works for me.

Comment: And for EFcore this is: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 35):

If you are using .Net core version then you need to install:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore nuget package.

And then:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: I found I had to remove the using: using System.Data.Entity; and replace it with you proposed to make it work. I had issues with both of the usings included together. Thanks for input

Answer (score 7):

Some further help for others experiencing this issue **even after including the using directive**. Jon mentioned it but I just want to make it clear as even after reading the answer I was stuck for a while, sorry if it seems obvious but might save someone else some time.

The issue for me was the reference, which was **Entity Framework**. After using Nuget to install EF the `.Include()` worked as usual.

This threw me because the same code with the `.Include()` was working in my main project (MVC app) but wasn't working in a different project in the same solution, even with the `using`, as it was missing EF. Hope this saves someone else some time.

Answer (score 6):

(I am using EF 7 with ASP.NET 5 Preview, DNX 5.0 Framework)

Adding this solved mine -

using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

Note: It's not **System**.Data.Entity

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the method Jon is talking about, you'll need to import the following namespace:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions is a type, and not a namespace, so I don't think this compiles. You can get access to these extensions by adding 'using System.Data.Entity;' in your class file. This was my experience with EF6 anyway, perhaps things were different when this reply was added.

Comment: what nuget package needs to be imported

Answer (score -2):

If you deploy directly to your repository, you can use `Include()`, as per example code below:

```
public IQueryable<Colaborador> FindAll()
{
     var retRepository = from colaborador in All()
                            .Include(x => x.Cliente)
                            select colaborador;

     return retRepository;
}
```