# system.linq.IQueryable does not contain a definition for 'To'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get an error in this code:

this is the code:

```
  public IHttpActionResult  Get()
    {
        var books = unit.Books.All;

        var response = books.To<BookDto>();

        return Ok(response);
    }
```

and right on books.To()  I am getting this error:

> system.linq.IQueryable does not contain a definition for 'To' and
>   extension method 'to' accepting a first argument of type 
>   'system.linq.IQueryable' could be found. you you missing a using 
>   directive or an assembly reference?

I looked at this but no help.

[IQueryable<T> does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017579/iqueryablet-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-include-and-no-extension-metho)

I have using System.Data.Entity; and also I have installed the EF from NuGet , but as the solution in the link I cant get the "QueryableExtensions" available in

```
 using System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions
```

Comment: Are you trying to cast the IQueryable to a List of BookDto?

Comment: Where do you think the `To` method is defined?  It's not a standard EF method that I'm aware of/

Comment: You have a function called `Ok`? What is its signature? (specifically, what argument type does it accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QueryableExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx) doesn't appear to contain any function named `To`, nor have I have ever heard of this method, so I suspect you're barking up the wrong tree in that regard.

You likely need one of the following:

1. `var response = books.ToList();` for a List of books
2. `var response = books.Cast<BookDto>();` to cast each objects in `books` to `BookDto`
3. `var response = books.Select(book => new BookDto(book));` to construct a sequence of `BookDto` objects from `books`, assuming there is a suitable constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`IQueryable.To<T>` isn't a thing. If you're trying to convert to a different type, you'll likely need to use `Select`, eg.

```
var response = books.Select(book => new BookDto()); //Insert transformation logic into the new object initialization.
```

If you're trying to make a list, then simply do this:

```
var response = books.ToList();
```