# Entity Framework Core does not contain a definition for 'Include'

Tags: c#

I am trying to work with Entity Framework Core 1.0 and trying to utilize the .Include when filling objects through the dbcontext.

```
        EFTestContext context = new EFTestContext();
        var testEntity = context.TestEntity
            .Include(t => t.TestEntity2)
            .ToList();
```

It give me the error

does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found

The only similar thing I found so far in Stackoverflow is

[IQueryable<T> does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017579/iqueryablet-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-include-and-no-extension-metho)

But adding the using statement

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Just give me the error

The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Anyone know what I need to get the Include to show up with WF Core 1.0?

Comment: Silly question, but do you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` in your code. You mentioned `using System.Data.Entity;`

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Per this example on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/Querying/Querying/RelatedData/Sample.cs#L2) here are the using's:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

That was what I was missing.. Much thanks!

Comment: The github link is dead