# How to join two tables using Entity Framework and match foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to C# and Entity Framework so I am getting myself really confused - apologies about this.

I currently have a database with two tables, `Artists` and `Albums`.

I would like to display a list of all albums on a page and have the corresponding `ArtistID` (foreign key on `Artist` page) linked to it.

I am trying to join these two tables together to render them on my `AllAlbums` page.

Could somebody look at my code and point me in the right direction?

Currently, my page only renders out all albums, and has no relationship with artists.

I will post the appropriate code snippets I have thus far.

AllAlbum.cshtml.cs

```
public class AllAlbumModel : PageModel
{
    DatabaseContext _Context;

    public AllAlbumModel(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
    {
        _Context = databasecontext;
    }

    public List<Album> AlbumList { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var data = (from albumlist in _Context.albums
                    select albumlist).ToList();

        AlbumList = data;
    }
}
```

Album.cs

```
[Table("albums")]
public class Album
{
    [Key]
    public int AlbumId {get; set;}
    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Album ID")]
    public string Title {get; set;}
    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Title")]
    public int ArtistId {get; set;}
}
```

Artist.cs

```
[Table("artists")]
public class Artist
{
    [Key]
    public int ArtistId {get; set;}
    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Album ID")]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Title")]
}
```

DatabaseContext.cs

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Album> albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> artists { get; set; }
}
```

AllAlbum.cshtml

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("AlbumId")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Title")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("ArtistId")
            </th>
            <th>Edit | Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.AlbumList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlbumId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArtistId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./AllAlbum" asp-route-id="@item.AlbumId">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./AllAlbum" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this album record?');" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.AlbumId">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Your query is only selecting values from the Albums table and not "joining" it with the artists table.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework should pick up that `ArtistId` on the `Album` class is a foreign key to the `Artist` table. Then the query that generates the data could be:

```
var albumList = _Context.albums.Include(x => x.artists).ToList();
```

Using `.Include()` will generate a query that joins the tables. For a more verbose query you could generate your own like this:

```
var albumsAndArtists = (from albumList in _Context.albums
                       join artistList in _Context.artists
                       on artistList.ArtistId 
                       equals albumList.ArtistId
                       select new 
                       {
                           Album = albumList,
                           Artist = artistList
                       })
                       .ToList();
```

To use the first query with the `.Include()` you will need to add:

```
public virtual Artist artists { get; set; }
```

In the `Album` class. This will enable lazy loading and will allow the use of `.Include()`.

Comment: When using this query, VSCode underlines both artistList and albumList on lines 3 and 4 as errors, hovering over, it reads "The name 'artistList' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'."

Using dotnet run also gives this error

Comment: Then you should swap them. Instead of `artistList.ArtistId equals albumList.ArtistId` try `albumList.ArtistId equals artistLIst.ArtistId`. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Also to use `Include` you may require the namespace statement `using System.Data.Entity`

Answer (score 3):

In your album class add a foreignkey linking to the artist:

```
[ForeignKey("ArtistId")] 
public virtual Artist Artist {get; set;}
```

Then include the artist where you get the data:

```
var data = _Context.albums
.Include(x => x.Artist)
.ToList();
```

Artist data is then available to you in your cshtml for example as `item.Artist...`

Comment: Could you show me exactly where to put that first block of code? Sorry, i am a noob. I am putting it in my Artist.cs file alongside the other links and i am getting errors?

Comment: Put it in the album class after the last line of your posted code

Comment: Just added it in, after adding the second block, 'Include' is red underlined with the message

"'DbSet<Album>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<Album>'"

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107228/entity-framework-core-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-include#39107344