# Context always returns null value

Tags: asp.net, api, entity-framework-core

I am new in using Entity Framework Core and I just don't know why I always got a null value in my `DbSet` when there are records in my database.

here is my `dbcontext`. I generate my code using EF Core Power Tools

```
public partial class dbContext : DbContext
{
   public dbContext(){}
   ...
   public virtual DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshToken { get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
   
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
     modelBuilder.Entity<RefreshToken>(entity =>
     {
        entity.Property(e => e.Token)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(255)
              .IsUnicode(false);
     }
     
     modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(entity =>
     {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        ...
     }
     ...
   }
}
```

**RefreshToken Class**

```
public partial class RefreshToken
{
   [Key]
   [JsonIgnore]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

**Users Class**

```
public partial class Users
{
   public Users()
   {
       RefreshToken = new HashSet<RefreshToken>();
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   [JsonIgnore]
   public virtual ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshToken { get; set; }

}
```

But when I call this method I always got null RefreshToken

```
private Users getUserByRefreshToken(string token)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshToken.Any(t => t.Token == token));



        if (user == null)
            throw new AppException("Invalid token");

        return user;
    }
```

The `var user` have data but the `u.RefreshToken` is always null even though the `string token` has value and it has the same value in `RefreshToken database table`. Please help me.

[image: SS of the error]

Answer (score 0):

Add `.Include()` to [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) the related data for `RefreshToken`.

```cs
var user = _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.RefreshToken)
    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshToken.Any(t => t.Token == token));
```

Comment: I tried it sir but it doesn't have `.Include()`. My RefreshToken entity has a FK `usersId` btw

Comment: Do you import `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` as mentioned in this question: [Entity Framework Core does not contain a definition for 'Include'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39107228/8017690)?